# Is there any use to instantiating an enum with new?

Tags: c#

C#'s compiler doesn't complain when you instantiate an `enum` using `new`:

```
enum Foo
{
    Bar
}

Foo x = new Foo();
```

`x` will then be a `Foo` with value `Bar`.

Does `new Foo()` have any use I'm not aware of? Or am I just boxing and immediately unboxing an enum value?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`new T()`, when `T` is a value type, is not a boxing operation. It is the same thing as `default(T)`. `Foo x = new Foo();`, `Foo x = default(Foo)`, and `Foo x = Foo.Bar;` all do exactly the same thing.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx):

> **Initializing Value Types**
>
> ```
> int myInt = new int();
> ```
>
> –or–
>
> ```
> int myInt = 0;
> ```
>
> Using the new operator calls the default constructor of the specific type and assigns the default value to the variable. In the preceding example, the default constructor assigned the value 0 to myInt. For more information about values assigned by calling default constructors, see [Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

Comment: It is worth noting that `Foo x = new Foo()` does not automatically create a `Foo`. It will initialize a foo only if there's one with the value of 0. Have a look: http://ideone.com/4Oj54P

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I thought Enums could not be null. What would Foo be if there isn't one at 0?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Have a look at the ideone-link. It is not null and it's type is `FooBar`, but it's kind of undefined. So we should always create an enum variable explicitely.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `new Foo()` will always be `default(Foo)` when `Foo` is any value type, and for `enum`s that will always be `(Foo)0`, regardless of whether a constant of that value exists. It's not kind of undefined, it's normal for enumeration variables to be able to hold values that do not correspond to any constant (think of flags).

Comment: Using "new someEnumType()" for something that is not a reference type seems to obfuscate the language, can anyone comment on what the motivation was for allowing this?

Answer (score 6):

At an IL level there is no difference between `Foo.Bar` and `new Foo()`.  Both will evaluate to the same set of IL opcodes

```
L_0001: ldc.i4.0 
L_0002: stloc.0
```

The only case these operations translate into different IL is when the `new` operation is done generically

```
void Method<T>() where T : struct {
  T local = new T();
}

Method<Foo>();
```

In this particular case `new` will produce a different set of op codes

```
L_0005: ldloca.s e3
L_0007: initobj !!T
```

Other than this somewhat esoteric difference, there is no practical difference between `Foo.Bar` and `new Foo()`

Comment: Worth pointing out: it's still not `new` that's different, then: `default(T)` compiles to the exact same `ldloca.s`/`initobj` for me in a generic method.

Answer (score 4):

See [MSDN's entry on the System.Enum Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx), particularly the section labeled **Instantiating an Enumeration Type**.

From what I understand, creating an instance of an `Enum` gives you the default value for that `Enum` (which is `0`).

**Example (taken directly from the MSDN article):**

```
public class Example
{
   public enum ArrivalStatus { Late=-1, OnTime=0, Early=1 };
   public static void Main()
   {
      ArrivalStatus status1 = new ArrivalStatus();
      Console.WriteLine("Arrival Status: {0} ({0:D})", status1);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       Arrival Status: OnTime (0)
```